# Using Chrome Dev Tools Code Folding Shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

On the Settings > Preferences > Source we can [enable Code Folding](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-73/#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20code%20folding%3A,Preferences%20%3E%20Sources%20enable%20Code%20folding.) on the Chrome Dev. But I didn't find a way to use keyboard shortcuts to, eg. collapse all, etc. Did look for in the Shortcuts section window and in the Full Listings also, but no success. I'm assuming we can't do it on the current version. In case someone knows about it, I'll be very happy to know it too.

Answer (score 8):

There's no such hotkey so try suggesting this feature on https://crbug.com.

Meanwhile you can add it manually:

1. make sure "code folding" is enabled in devtools settings (in the "Sources" group)
2. run this code in **devtools-on-devtools** (see the instruction below)

   ```
   [
     ['Shift-Ctrl-[', 'fold'],
     ['Shift-Ctrl-]', 'unfold'],
     ['Shift-Ctrl--', 'foldAll'],
     ['Shift-Ctrl-=', 'unfoldAll'],
   ].forEach(([key, cmd]) => {
     CodeMirror.keyMap['devtools-common'][key] = CodeMirror.commands[cmd];
   });
   ```
3. close devtools-on-devtools

This will last only for the current devtools instance.

For convenience you can save the code in [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) and run it later from there or by typing the snippet name in the commands palette (<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-P</kbd> hotkey).

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Does work with 'foldAll' and 'unfoldAll', but doesn't with 'fold' and unfold' ???

Comment: It works for me in Windows so I guess you may have to adjust the hotkeys if your OS is different. Also make sure the block you're trying it on is actually foldable and cursor is at the beginning of the block. To make folding work at any place inside the block you can write your own function (not trivial but doable).

Comment: Many thanks, but needs to edit, you wrote 'unfoldAll' two times.

Comment: Edited. I've switched to supported hotkeys that actually work in devtools. Those old ones were two different hotkeys to invoke unfoldAll in the sublime keymap of CodeMirror from which I've copied the code and they didn't work in devtools.

Comment: I can't open devtools on devtools under electron. Do you know how to bypass this?

Comment: chrome devtools has been updated to use CodeMirror 6, where the command methods require a codeMirror instance as argument, so you could merge my answer into yours as an update. (document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror")[1].CodeMirror)

Answer (score 5):

CodeMirror 6 supports the folding shortcuts natively (per [foldKeymap](https://codemirror.net/docs/ref/#language.foldKeymap)):

- Ctrl-Shift-[ (Cmd-Alt-[ on macOS): Fold the lines that are selected, if possible.
- Ctrl-Shift-] (Cmd-Alt-] on macOS): Unfold folded ranges on selected lines.
- Ctrl-Alt-[: Fold all top-level foldable ranges.
- Ctrl-Alt-]: Unfold all folded code.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer is great, but chrome devtools has been updated since to use CodeMirror 6, which requires a codeMirror instance to be passed to the functions:

```
CodeMirror.commands.foldAll();
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operation')
    at CodeMirror.commands.foldAll (foldcode.js:105:8)
    at <anonymous>:1:21
```

line 104-109 from foldcode.js:

```
  CodeMirror.commands.foldAll = function(cm) {
    cm.operation(function() {
      for (var i = cm.firstLine(), e = cm.lastLine(); i <= e; i++)
        cm.foldCode(CodeMirror.Pos(i, 0), null, "fold");
    });
  };
```

I could solve it by debugging a codemirror event to save the `cm` instance as a global variable (temp1), but I would appreciate if someone could have a better solution to this that can be automated.

Edit: I found the codeMirror instance at `document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror")[1].CodeMirror`, so a working solution is:

```
CodeMirror.commands.foldAll(document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror")[1].CodeMirror)
```

the shortcut setting still doesn't seem to work though.
(with

```
 CodeMirror.keyMap["devtools-common"]["Ctrl-k"]=function()
{let {CodeMirror:instance}=
 document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror")[1];
 CodeMirror.commands.foldAll(instance);
};
```

)

Edit 2: oh, it just needed capital K, so "Ctrl-K". Now the shortcut works too. hurrah

btw i've commented on the folding feature's thread on chromium bugtracker to include this, because it is incredibly useful for skimming files while editing/reading. No response yet, idk if anyone's even paying attention to comments there anymore:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328431